# Selecionar o país e trazer o estado

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, select

Tenho um código que esté em `Codeigniter`. Ele tem a página para cadastrar um usuário. Nessa página pede pra ele colocar o país e o estado que ele mora. Precisava que ele ao selecionar um país viesse os estados correspondentes aquele país. Encontrei um arquivo Javascript que serve para fazer isso. No teste que eu fiz ele funcionou perfeitamente, mas na hora de colocar no meu código ele não traz a lista dos países que estão dentro do array.

O arquivo em Javascript é esse:

```
// Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2]="Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3]="Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4]="Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5]="Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6]="Anguilla";
s_a[7]="Antartica";



function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );

    stateElement.length=0;  // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Selecione seu estado','');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId){
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length=0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Selecione seu país','-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if( stateElementId ){
        countryElement.onchange = function(){
            populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId );
        };
    }
}
```

Meu HTML está assim:

```
<session>
       <label class="select">
              <select id="country" name="country">
                     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">país</option>
              </select>
       </label>
</session>
```

Na pagina de teste coloquei essa função:

```
<script language="javascript">
    populateCountries("country", "state");
</script>
```

Mas ao colocar na minha página fala que não é definida.

Comment: Fez a include do javascript que contem suas funções?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando um `select` para receber as cidades.

Veja que no metodo  `populateCountries` você passa o id da cidade e do estado.

**Adicione o HTML:**

```
<select id="state" name="state">
 <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione o estado</option>
</select>
```

Veja funcionando.

```js
// Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2] = "Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3] = "Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4] = "Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5] = "Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6] = "Anguilla";
s_a[7] = "Antartica";

populateCountries("country", "state");




function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {



    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Selecione seu estado', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Selecione seu país', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function() {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<label class="select">
   <select id="country" name="country">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">país</option>
   </select>
   <select id="state" name="state">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione o estado</option>
   </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Com essas alterações funcionou certinho. Só que quando você abre pela primeira vez ele continua não aparecendo, mas quando você recarrega ela aparece

Comment: @Ketlin sim, é porque você não selecionou nenhum pais ainda.

Comment: Não na parte dos estados e nos países acontecia isso, mas já consegui resolver. Obrigada!

Comment: @Ketlin que bom que conseguiu, sucesso ai.

Answer (score 0):

A função `populateCountries` necessita de dois elementos `select` para gerar o codigo que você deseja.

Assim o único ajuste que você deve fazer é alterar seu `HTML`.

```
<select name="country" id="country"></select>
<select name="state" id="state"></select>
```

E no js:

```
populateCountries('country', 'state');
```

[Seja funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/3pm4uu72/)

Comment: Eu esqueci de colocar, mas em outro <label> eu tinha o select para o estado. O meu código não está nem aparecendo os nomes dos países para escolher.