# Javascript: Se dropdownlist for selecionada, como carregar os campos?

Tags: javascript, html

Boa Tarde Galera,

Como faço para carregar alguns campos se valor da Dropdownlist for selecionada?

Comment: meu amigo, poste o código com sua dropdownlist e o que você quer carregar.

Comment: Acho que aqui pode te dá um norte. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87411/selecionar-o-pa%C3%ADs-e-trazer-o-estado/87417#87417

Comment: O que eu queria era exatamente o que o Erick Gallani enviou, obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser feito assim

O html

```
<select id='meuDropdown'>
    <option value='1'>Opção 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Opção 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Opção 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Opção 4</option>
</select>

<input type='text' id='meuInputText' style='display: none' />
```

O javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var dropdown = document.getElementById('meuDropdown');

        function onDropdownChanged()
        {
            console.log(dropdown.selectedIndex);
            //aqui você pode fazer o que quiser com o valor selecionado
            //por exemplo
            if(dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value == 2) {
                //faz algo quando o valor selecionado for 2
                console.log('Selecionou o valor 2');

                //mostra o input quando o valor selecionado for 2
                var meuInput = document.getElementById('meuInputText');
                meuInput.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        if (dropdown.addEventListener)
        {
            dropdown.addEventListener('change', onDropdownChanged, false);
        }
        else
        {
            // suporte para o IE
            dropdown.attachEvent('onchange', onDropdownChanged, false);
        }
    </script>
```

Exemplo no JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5a0bqo8o/2/

Espero ter ajudado