# Combobox estado - cidade PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Isso está preenchendo corretamente a combobox de estados. Como procedo para agora, ao selecionar o estado a combobox de cidades referentes ao estado selecionado seja preenchida? Como implemento o "carregaCidades()"?

```html
    <?
 
  //seleciona todas as cidades quando o pais nao for o Brasil
 $sql = "select distinct loc_cidade, id_local from local where id_pais = '" . $id_pais . "' and loc_cidade <> '' "; 
 $sql .= " and loc_tipo = 'C' ";
 $sql .= " order by loc_cidade";
 $local = Consulta($sql, $conexao); 
 
 $rs = mysql_query("select distinct loc_uf from local where id_pais = '27' ORDER BY loc_uf ASC");
 
 
?>


<select name="estado" id="estado" onChange="carregaCidades()">
 <option selected value="estado">Estado</option>
    <?php while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $reg->id_local ?>"><?php echo $reg->loc_uf ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
        
    <div id="load_cidades">
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade">
     <option value="">Aguardando o estado</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Aqui pode te audar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87411/selecionar-o-pa%C3%ADs-e-trazer-o-estado/87417#87417

Comment: Precisa utilizar ajax, no `onchange()` do combo estado crie uma função que faz uma chamada ajax a um arquivo php, depois pegue o retorno e trate. é mais ou menos essa a ideia.

Answer (score 2):

No seu arquivo de *scripts* jQuery, adicione uma função para cuidar do evento `change`

```
jQuery("#estado").on('change',function(){
  var estadoSelecionado = jQuery( this ).val();
  //e aqui vc executa o restante do código para carregar as cidades
  //chamando por ajax a página que carrega a cidade...
  //e vc adiciona a estadoSelecionado como parâmetro
});
```

Dessa forma você não prende a função na tag HTML. Um bom exemplo está neste [link](http://www.daviferreira.com/posts/populando-selects-de-cidades-e-estados-com-ajax-php-e-jquery)