# Construção de link de pesquisa, combinando select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, e-commerce

estou com um pequeno problema com a construção de um filtro de pesquisa para meu site.

Enfim, preciso de um filtro que mostre opções que estão relacionadas com o select anterior exemplo:

jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/u4eb27rb/

```js
var arr_cidades = {
  sp: ["Sorocaba", "Boituva", "Tatuí"],
  rj: ["Uma cidade do Rio", "Outra cidade"]
}

function escolha() {
  var estado = document.querySelector("#estado");
  var cidade = document.querySelector("#cidade");

  cidade.disabled = false;

  cidade.innerHTML = "";

  switch (estado.value) {
    case "sp":
      for (i in arr_cidades.sp) {
        cidade.innerHTML += "<option>" + arr_cidades.sp[i] + "</option>"
      };
      break;
    case "rj":
      for (i in arr_cidades.rj) {
        cidade.innerHTML += "<option>" + arr_cidades.rj[i] + "</option>"
      };
      break;
    default:
      cidade.innerHTML += "<option>- Selecione uma cidade -</option>";
      cidade.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Estado</span>
<br>
<select id='estado' onchange="escolha()">
  <option value=''>- Selecione um Estado -</option>
  <option value='sp'>SP</option>
  <option value='rj'>RJ</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span>Cidade</span>
<br>
<select id='cidade' disabled="true">
  <option value=''>- Selecione uma Cidade -</option>
</select>
```

Mas preciso que o comportamento de acesso desse link seja da seguinte forma:

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvwGVj

```js
var departamento = document.getElementById('departamento');
var categoria= document.getElementById('categoria');
var montadora= document.getElementById('montadora');
var input = document.getElementById('filtro-j');
input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // não precisarias disto se o input fosse <button type="button">Filtrar</button>
    var newLocation  = ['http://www.rs1.com.br', departamento.value, categoria.value, montadora.value].join('/');
  location.href = newLocation;
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <select id="departamento" >
        <option type="text" value="">Selecione o departamento...</option>
        <option type="text" value="automotivo">Automotivo</option>
    </select>
    <select id="categoria" >
        <option type="text" value="">Selecione a categoria...</option>
        <option type="text" value="pastilhas-de-freio">Pastilhas de Freio</option>
    </select>
    <select id="montadora" >
        <option type="text" value="">Selecione a montadora...</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Agrale">Agrale</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Audi">Audi</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Cadillac">Cadillac</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:CitroÃ«n">Citroën</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Daewoo">Daewoo</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Ford">Ford</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Gurgel">Gurgel</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Honda">Honda</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Iveco">Iveco</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Jac Motors">Jac Motors</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Jeep">Jeep</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Kia Motors">Kia Motors</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Lancia">Lancia</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Land Rover">Land Rover</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Marcopolo">Marcopolo</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Mercedes Benz">Mercedes Benz</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Nissan">Nissan</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Peugeot">Peugeot</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Renault">Renault</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Scania">Scania</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Seat">Seat</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:SsangYong">SsangYong</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Subaru">Subaru</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Troller">Troller</option>
        <option type="text" value="?fq=specificationFilter_351:Troller">Volkswagen</option>
    </select>
  <button id="filtro-j" type="button">Filtrar</button>
</div>
```

No caso se eu selecionar o departamento "Vestuário" A construção do link se da a seguinte forma exemplo:

Departamento          Categoria         Especificação
 Vestuário             Capacete          Fechado
                                         Aberto

O link final em teoria ficaria assim no botão filtrar:

```
http://www.rs1.com.br/capacete?fq=specificationFilter_29:Aberto
```

isso se o usuário selecionasse a opção `Vestuário>Capacete>Aberto`

Quero montar um filtro dessa maneira, o primeiro nível que se chama vestuário é apenas uma forma visual de saber onde o usuário deseja encontrar os itens do site.

Conseguiria fazer isso ?

Update: consegui gerar o primeiro nível do link, mas o ultimo nível não consegui resolver, para comparar o segundo select...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjPWYR?editors=101

Comment: Nesse link que colocaste onde está a parte "vestuário"? Tens algum objeto ou array com os links possiveis de cada categoria? tipo àrvore de opções?

Comment: sim tenho sim, se caso ele selecionar Vestuário, teria que trazer as opções que tenho que no caso seriam alguns exemplos seriam: 
Capacete,
Calça,
Jaqueta,
Luva,
Botas já a especificação é algo que teria que ver na plataforma como ficariam... mas se conseguir fazer para um departamento, acredito que seja a mesma coisa para os outros que for adicionar.

Comment: Seria isso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87411/selecionar-o-pa%C3%ADs-e-trazer-o-estado/87417#87417

Comment: Basicamente, mas no final construir o link no botão filtrar com as opções selecionadas.